# How to make unit test data dynamic for sql database testing via sqlalchemy and py.test?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, pytest

I'm developing unit test for CRUD operation on my database via py.test.

The issue is creating test data is becoming a hassle as the database keep growing. I'm currently making dictionaries manually and checking values.

My concern is, this may not be the proper way going forward. 
How can I make mock data for CRUD operation more dynamic?

Comment: Your question is quite broad. Here's a good read about sqla and pytest https://gist.github.com/inklesspen/4504383

Comment: You can use [Mixer](https://github.com/klen/mixer) to create fake data.